# Cart button disappears on Mobile (Tablet Portrait and Smartphone)

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

On this [website](https://misternice.ch/) the "Cart" button (the **top-right** Cart icon with 0 Artikel) disappear on Mobile (Tablet Portrait and Smartphone).

How can I make it visible also on those devices?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

## et-secondary-menu has display:none !important; set on smaller screen. [image]